# How to correctly replace the function in c

Tags: c, function, loops, for-loop

So the code below works fine, but I want to use `move_possible()` instead of commented area, I tried to follow the same principle but failed to do so. The first part works correctly but the second part does not

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   /* Play a game of connect 4.
    * represents red, o represents yellow discs.
   */
   const char *discs = "*o";
   char grid[rows * columns];
   memset(grid, ' ', rows * columns);
   int turn, finish = 0;

   for(turn = 0; turn < rows * columns && !finish; turn++)
   {
      out_grid(grid);   
      // Checking if move is possible
      while(!drop_disc(grid, turn % 2, discs))
      {
         out_grid(grid);   
         puts("You can't play in that column \n");
      }
      finish = win(grid);
   } 
   out_grid(grid);

   if(turn == rows * columns && !finish)
   {
      puts("It is a tie");
   } 
   else 
   {
      turn--;
      printf("Congratulations! Player %d won!\n", turn % 2 + 1);
   }
   return 0;
}
void out_grid(char *grid)
{
   /*Shows the grid:
    * represents red discs.
    o represents yellow discs */
   int row, col;
   for(row = 0; row < rows; row++)
   {
      for(col = 0; col < columns; col++)
      {
         printf("  %c ",  grid[columns * row + col]);
      }
      puts("                             ");
   }
   puts("  1   2   3   4   5   6   7\n");
}
int drop_disc(char *grid, int player, const char *discs)
{
   // Drop the disc
   int row, col = 0;
   printf("Player %d:\nEnter your move: ", player + 1, discs[player]);

   while(1)
   { 
      if(1 != scanf("%d", &col) || col > 7 || col < 1)
      {
         while(getchar() != '\n');
         puts("Enter valid number");
      } else 
      { 
         break;
      }
   }
   col--;
/////////////////////////////////////////
   for(row = rows - 1; row >= 0; row--)
   {
      if(grid[columns * row + col] == ' ')
      {
         grid[columns * row + col] = discs[player];
         return 1;
      }
   }
   return 0;
//////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

The code below with replaced function, prints the discs on the top row's columns and nowhere else when I run it

The way it should work is: the disc should be dropped to 1st row and the as follows
So I guess the problem is with the code below

```
int move_possible(char *grid)
{
   int row, col = 0;
   for(row = rows - 1; row >= 0; row--)
   {
      if(grid[columns * row + col] == ' ')
      {
         return 1;
      }
      else
      {
         return 0;
      }
      col++;
   }
   return 0;
}
int drop_disc(char *grid, int player, const char *discs)
{
   // Drop the disc
   int row, col = 0;
   printf("Player %d:\nEnter your move: ", player + 1, discs[player]);

   while(1)
   { 
      if(1 != scanf("%d", &col) || col > 7 || col < 1)
      {
         while(getchar() != '\n');
         puts("Enter valid number");
      } else 
      { 
         break;
      }
   }
   col--;

   if(move_possible(grid) == 1){
         grid[columns * row + col] = discs[player];
         return 1;
      }
   return 0;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It difficult to follow the rules of the game. Add observed and expected outputs of out_grid().

Comment: In move_possible remove the else clause in the loop. The effect of the else clause is that if the loop encounters an occupied slot before it encounters an unoccupied slot the function will return false. What you want, and what the first version of the code does, is to set the first unoccupied slot, even if it found occupied slots earlier.